# How logstash parses a log file?

Tags: logstash

I have started working on ELK recently and I am completely new to it. I wanted to know how logstash goes about parsing a log file. I have a file as input and elasticsearch as output. How does logstash parse the log file internally using filter plugins?

Comment: Do you mean, "How do I use Logstash?" or "How, functionally, does Logstash work?"

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/filter-plugins.html

Comment: Will I am clear about how do I use logstash. I wanted to how functionally does logstash works ? For json input I think it takes json objects one by one but for a log file which does not have any proper structure , how does logstash applies its filter-plugins. please ignore if I sound stupid.

Comment: Not stupid, I just wanted to clarify what you were asking

Comment: I may try to give this an answer, but in the meantime, try reading around the source https://github.com/elastic/logstash

Comment: Thanks Will, I will go through and get back

Comment: Thanks Will, I got what I wanted . thanks for respnding.